# In R's data.table, how is the key of a data.table preserved into subsets referenced using .SD?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the `data.table` package to complete some analyses. One of the steps I am taking involves using the `by =` function to obtain aggregate statistics. However, the aggregates must be calculated on the unique results in each `by` subset. I have been using `unique` and keys to ensure that each `by` group consists of distinct records. Something vaguely like the below:

```
dt_new <- dt_old[,uFunc_MyFunction(x = unique(.SD)),by = grouping_var]
```

I noticed that the key on `.SD` seemed to vary based on the key set for `dt_old` and the `by =` statement. Obviously, this was having an effect on whether my resulting subsets were unique or not.

I wanted to get some clarity, so I wrote the below.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1554)
dt_example <- data.table(id = 1:50,
                         site = sample(x = c("A","B","C"),
                                       size = 50,
                                       replace = TRUE,
                                       prob = c(0.4,0.4,0.2)),
                         group = sample(x = c("Eta","Mu","Omicron","Psi"),
                                        size = 50,
                                        replace = TRUE),
                         team = sample(x = 1:3,
                                       size = 50,
                                       replace = TRUE,
                                       prob = c(0.2,0.3,0.5)))

setkey(x = dt_example,
       group,
       team)

> dt_example[,as.list(key(.SD)),by = site]
   site    V1   V2
1:    B group team
2:    A group team
3:    C group team

setkey(x = dt_example,
       site,
       group,
       team)

> dt_example[,as.list(key(.SD)),by = site]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: site
```

What I am trying to understand is why, in the first version, the key for `.SD` is consistent, while, in the second version, `.SD` had no key at all. I think it has something to do with the fact that the `by =` column isn't directly included in `.SD`, which is breaking the key, but I wanted to confirm my logic.

So, my question is this: why does the subset of a data table, `.SD`, have no key when one of the columns which comprises the key of the parent data table is used as a `by` grouping variable?

Comment: This question is really just an FR.

Comment: @eddi What is an FR?

Comment: FR = Feature Request

Comment: Why would you run `unique(.SD)` by group in the first place? Feels very inefficient. Can't you just do `data_new <- unique(dt_old)` and then run your function by group?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sure, but that wouldn't answer my question about how the key gets passed between .SD and the parent. Also, if you have a lot of data, you might be loathe to create a second copy with just the uniques, which I think would happen in this case.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Strictly speaking, I'm just running `unique` on `.SD` prior to passing it to the function.

Comment: If you have a lot of data, running your analysis on a much smaller data while also avoiding `.SD` calls per group will save you a lot of time, but yeah, it will cost more memory in return. Though you could `rm` your old one and save both memory and time.

Comment: To be clear, I basically solved it in a similar way on my end. This question is mostly to ensure understanding. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, since it's sorted by `site, group, team`, while grouping by `site`, the key could be retained for `group, team` as the order would be maintained. The simplest answer is we seem to have missed this case. Could you please file an issue with just a link to this post?

As a work around, you can use the `by` argument in `unique` method for data.tables to specify the columns.

And as David pointed out, using `unique(.SD)` on every group seems unnecessary, but that's probably for another Q.

Comment: I'll log an issue momentarily. And I do agree that `unique(.SD)` is an unusual use case. I wouldn't really even expect it to be "fixed" - just was curious what happened under the hood.